# Order of null pointer checking

Tags: java, jvm, java-memory-model

These code comes from:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jcstress/file/tip/tests-custom/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jcstress/tests/volatiles/ReadAfterReadTest.java

```
public class ReadAfterReadTest {
    private final Holder h1 = new Holder();
    private final Holder h2 = h1;
    private static class Holder {
        int a;
        int trap;
    }
    @Actor
    public void actor1() {
        h1.a = 1;
    }
    @Actor
    public void actor2(II_Result r) {
        Holder h1 = this.h1;
        Holder h2 = this.h2;
        (*****)
        // Spam null-pointer check folding: try to step on NPEs early.
        // Doing this early frees compiler from moving h1.a and h2.a loads
        // around, because it would not have to maintain exception order anymore.
        (*****)
        h1.trap = 0;
        h2.trap = 0;

        // Spam alias analysis: the code effectively reads the same field twice,
        // but compiler does not know (h1 == h2) (i.e. does not check it, as
        // this is not a profitable opt for real code), so it issues two independent
        // loads.
        r.r1 = h1.a;
        r.r2 = h2.a;
    }
}
```

I cannot understand what does the author mean by the highlighted with             (*****) comment.

Answer (score 2):

Java spec requires to check `h1` and `h2` instances for null before polling their fields even without explicit NPE check - this feature is also knows as implicit null pointer check. Lets look at assembly code(generated by JIT):

```
0x00007f1fad2429f2: mov    %rbx,0x18(%rsp)
0x00007f1fad2429f7: mov    (%rsp),%rbx
0x00007f1fad2429fb: mov    0x10(%rsp),%rcx
0x00007f1fad242a00: mov    0x28(%rsp),%r10    ;*aload
0x00007f1fad242a05: mov    0x10(%rbx),%r11d   ;*getfield h1
0x00007f1fad242a09: mov    0xc(%r11),%edx     ;*getfield a
                                              ; implicit exception: dispatches to 0x00007f1fad242b37
0x00007f1fad242a0d: mov    %r12d,0x10(%r11)   ;*putfield trap
0x00007f1fad242a11: mov    0x14(%rbx),%r9d    ;*getfield h2
0x00007f1fad242a15: mov    %r12d,0x10(%r9)    ;*putfield trap
                                              ; implicit exception: dispatches to 0x00007f1fad242b49
0x00007f1fad242a19: mov    %r10,0x28(%rsp)
0x00007f1fad242a1e: mov    %rcx,0x10(%rsp)
```

where de-referencing the null pointer will cause SEGV signal to the process. VM has the SEGV handler which can handle this, and throw an appropriate NullPointerException(NPE).

This can be considered as a small compiler's barrier which can prevents some optimizations where exception should be thrown exactly at the place where it happened. This check provides guarantees that further execution of the code will not cause a NPE, so compiler can move `h1.a` and `h2.a` loads around, because it would not have to maintain exception order anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think he is trying to generate `NullPointerException` early. That is: If `h1` or `h2` would be null at this point, assigning `h1.trap = 0` would throw an NPE.

And the next lines explain why this helps:

`Doing this early frees compiler from moving h1.a and h2.a loads` - I think it is related to some optimizations that the compiler does and JIT.

The simplest way is to write a test class and generate the bytecode for the case when you try to access a passed variable value and when not and see the difference.

Or you can contact the author: Aleksey Shipilev (shade) @aleksey-shipilev

If you really want to understand, I think you need to read something about that:

[https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibm/library/it-haggar_bytecode/](http://[https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibm/library/it-haggar_bytecode/][1])
http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076060/build-ci-sdlc/compiler-optimizations.html

Comment: @aleksey-shipilev, can you comment on that please?